# ¿2 Computed en un v-for?

Tags: vue.js

Quería saber si existe la posibilidad de llamar a 2 métodos en un v-for, por ejemplo:

**Tengo este extracto de código**

```
             <ul>
                <li v-for="t in tareaPrio">
                    {{t.nombre}}
                    <small>
                        ({{t.prioridad}})
                    </small>
                </li>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="10" v-model="minimo">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Tarea que busca" v-model="busqueda">
            </ul>
```

Donde `v-for="t in "` apunta a un método llamado tareaPrio, existe la posibilidad de agregar otro método?

```
computed: {
tareaPrio() {
    return this.tareas.filter((tarea) => tarea.prioridad >= this.minimo);
},
buscarTarea(){
    return this.tareas.filter((tarea) => tarea.nombre.includes(this.busqueda));
    },
},
```

Si existiera la forma de hacerlo, ¿cual es?.

Comment: Si necesitas llamar a dos métodos, entonces es un problema de lógica de tu aplicación, más allá que se pueda hacer o no.

Comment: @Shaz estoy aprendiendo vue, pero quería saber si es posible o no, 1 es de búsqueda con un input range por prioridad, y el otro es de búsqueda por nombre input text.